# Why is my python code printing "function" and a lot of numbers?

Tags: python

So I need to make a program that simulates the Powerball.

```
import random

def powerball():
  randInt = 0
  first_bin = [1]
  for i in range(1,70):
    first_bin.append(i)
#Create second bin - a list of integers from 1-26
  sec_bin = [1]
  for i in range(1,27):
    sec_bin.append(i)

#Mix up the bins - .shuffle()
  random.shuffle(first_bin)
  random.shuffle(sec_bin)

#Select 5 numbers from bin 1
#for loop
#.pop() to pull a ball
#.randInt to pick a position in the list
  for i in range(65):
    first_bin.pop(randInt)

#Sort our list of 5 numbers
  first_bin.sort
#Pick the Powerball from bin 2 - .choice() & append that to our list of 5 numbers
  ball = random.choice(sec_bin)
  power = first_bin.append(ball)
#return our list
  return power

#main program - call the function and print the result
print(powerball())
```

Whenever I try to run the program, it prints "function powerball at 0x7f10b46283a0". It only started doing this after the last couple of lines. What's going wrong? I checked and it seems like it would run fine.

Comment: use () after the function name while calling.

Comment: @ppwater sorry I thought it was too long to enter

Comment: Similar problem: `first_bin.sort` doesn't do anything because you're not calling the function

Comment: @one how would I call it?

Comment: Gilseung's answer is correct

Comment: It just returns "none" for me. I don't know what I'm doing wrong because it looks like it would work.

Comment: And sort() is a function of list objects. You need to call the functions using parentheses... And there's other logic issues in the code such as randInt is always 0, and there's easier ways to get 5 values out of a list randomly

Comment: @OneCricketeer Gilseung's answer is correct, but it's not perfect there are more issues about the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### reason

that's because you do append and you assign that to the variable.

### how to fix it

try this code:

```
import random

def powerball():
  randInt = 0
  first_bin = [1]
  for i in range(1,70):
    first_bin.append(i)
#Create second bin - a list of integers from 1-26
  sec_bin = [1]
  for i in range(1,27):
    sec_bin.append(i)
  

#Mix up the bins - .shuffle()
  random.shuffle(first_bin)
  random.shuffle(sec_bin)

#Select 5 numbers from bin 1
#for loop
#.pop() to pull a ball
#.randInt to pick a position in the list
  for i in range(65):
    first_bin.pop(randInt)
#Sort our list of 5 numbers
  first_bin.sort() # fixed this sort -> sort()
#Pick the Powerball from bin 2 - .choice() & append that to our list of 5 numbers
  ball = random.choice(sec_bin)
  first_bin.append(ball) #added this
  power = first_bin #changed this
#return our list
  return power

#main program - call the function and print the result
print(powerball())
```

1. I fixed `power = first_bin.append(ball)` this is wrong. `append` just *appends* something to the list and it returns nothing(`none`). so just call it first and set power to `first_bin` like this: `power = first_bin`
2. use `print(powerball())` instead of `print(powerball)`
3. you have to use `sort()` instead of `sort`

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
print(powerball())
```

instead of `print(powerball)`.

Comment: it's just saying "none" now

Comment: It's saying none because the return is none. it's not just that issue

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is that you need to call the function, as mentioned.

The second is that `append` will modify the list, and always returns None, which you then return yourself. So, while the idea might be correct, you don't need another variable for it

For example

```
import random 
def powerball():
    first_bin = list(range(1, 70))
    random.shuffle(first_bin)
    result = sorted(first_bin[:5])
    ball = random.randint(1, 27) 
    result.append(ball)
    return result

print(powerball())
```